# How do I hold down a key in python?

Tags: python, keyboard, output

I have looked at multiple libraries such as 'pynput', 'pyautogui' and 'keyboard', and can't find a library that holds down a key for a certain amount of time or until a key is pressed. How would I do this. I would like it to be something more like "wwwwwww" - and so w is held down for x amount of time rather than it being "w"+"w"+"w"+"w"+"w"+"w"+"w"

I tried multiple things such as:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard as potato
import time

potato.wait('del')

pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui
time.sleep(5)

pyautogui.press('shift', 'shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift','shift',)
pyautogui.keyUp('w')

pyautogui.hold('w')
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.press('Ctrl')
pyautogui.keyUp('w')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your code simple

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press('w')
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.release('w')
```

Comment: Thank you, I found that this didn't work in notepad, and so it only returned 'w', but it works in the emulator i am using it in